# public void onClick(View v) causing application to crash

Tags: java, android, button

I want to have the user click one of two buttons to do a calculation but the  onClicklistiner`and the public void`onClick` causes the app to crash. 
However the same thing in a new blank java main works. both sets of code have been placed below. The button implementation code is the same only difference is the frist set of code sets the navigation drawer up

```
    package com.androidbelieve.tradingtechnicals;

    import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
    import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import android.view.Menu;

    import com.androidbelieve.drawerwithswipetabs.R;

    import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;

    import java.text.NumberFormat;


    public abstract class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


        DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
        NavigationView mNavigationView;
        FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
        FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
            mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.shitstuff);
            mNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);


            mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, new TabFragment()).commit();


            mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();


                    if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_formations) {
                        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, new fomations()).commit();

                    }

                    if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_main_menu) {
                        FragmentTransaction xfragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                        xfragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, new TabFragment()).commit();
                    }


                    if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.candle_sticks_drawer) {
                        FragmentTransaction xfragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                        xfragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, new candlesticks()).commit();
                    }


                    if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.candle_sticks_drawer) {
                        FragmentTransaction xfragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                        xfragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, new candlesticks()).commit();
                    }

                    if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_Stochastic) {
                        FragmentTransaction xfragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                        xfragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, new stochastic()).commit();
                    }

                    if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_Relative_strength) {
                        FragmentTransaction xfragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                        xfragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, new Relative_Strength()).commit();
                    }

                    if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_MACD) {
                        FragmentTransaction xfragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                        xfragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, new MACD()).commit();
                    }


                    if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_moving_averages) {
                        FragmentTransaction xfragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                        xfragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, new moving_averages()).commit();
                    }

                    if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_help) {
                        FragmentTransaction xfragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                        xfragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, new help()).commit();
                    }


                    if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_additional_content) {
                        FragmentTransaction xfragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                        xfragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, new additional_content_1()).commit();
                    }

                    if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_p_e) {
                        FragmentTransaction xfragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                        xfragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, new Fundemental_metrics()).commit();
                    }

                    if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_cdf) {
                        FragmentTransaction xfragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                        xfragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, new eq_cfd()).commit();
                    }


                    return false;


                }

            });


            android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.app_name,
                    R.string.app_name);

            mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

            mDrawerToggle.syncState();

            AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);


        }


        public void onClick(View v)


        {
            switch (v.getId()){

                case R.id.button1:




            EditText working_capital = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.working_capital);
            EditText total_assets = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.total_assets);
            EditText ebit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ebit);
            EditText market_val_eq = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.market_value_of_equity);
            EditText book_val_lib = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.book_lib);
            EditText retained_ern = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.retained_earnings);
            EditText sales = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sales);

            TextView answer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
            TextView comment = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.comment);


            if (working_capital.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0 || total_assets.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0 || ebit.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0 || market_val_eq.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0 || book_val_lib.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0 || retained_ern.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0 || sales.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {

                answer.setText("Result");


            } else {

                double num1 = Double.parseDouble(working_capital.getText().toString());
                double num2 = Double.parseDouble(total_assets.getText().toString());
                double num3 = Double.parseDouble(ebit.getText().toString());
                double num4 = Double.parseDouble(market_val_eq.getText().toString());
                double num5 = Double.parseDouble(book_val_lib.getText().toString());
                double num6 = Double.parseDouble(retained_ern.getText().toString());
                double num7 = Double.parseDouble(sales.getText().toString());


                double sum = 1.2 * (num1 / num2) + 1.4 * (num6 / num2) + 3.3 * (num3 / num2) + 0.6 * (num4 / num5) + (num7 / num2);

                answer.setText(String.format("%.2f", sum));

                if (sum >= 2.99) {

                    comment.setText("Successful");

                } else if (sum <= 1.81) {

                    comment.setText("Unsuccessful");

                } else {
                    comment.setText("Grey zone");
                }


            }

                    break;

                case R.id.button2:

                    ebit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ebit);
                    EditText net_profit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.net_profit);
                    EditText assets = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.assets);
                    EditText Sales = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sales);

                    EditText Equity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.equity);
                    TextView answer2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result2);

            if (assets.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0 || net_profit.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0 || Sales.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0 || Equity.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {
                answer2.setText("Result");

            } else {

                double num8 = Double.parseDouble(net_profit.getText().toString());
                double num9 = Double.parseDouble(assets.getText().toString());
                double num10 = Double.parseDouble(ebit.getText().toString());
                double num11 = Double.parseDouble(Equity.getText().toString());

                double sum2 = (num8 / num10) * (num10 / num9) * (num9 / num11);

                answer2.setText(String.format("%.2f", sum2));
            }
            }
        }
    }



package engineeringtrader.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

        button1.setOnClickListener(this);


        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

       switch (v.getId()){

            case R.id.button1:


                EditText working_capital = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.working_capital);
                EditText total_assets = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.total_assets);
                EditText ebit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ebit);
                EditText market_val_eq = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.market_value_of_equity);
                EditText book_val_lib = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.book_lib);
                EditText retained_ern = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.retained_earnings);
                EditText sales = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sales);

                TextView answer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
                TextView comment = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.comment);

                if (working_capital.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0 || total_assets.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0 || ebit.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0 || market_val_eq.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0 || book_val_lib.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0 || retained_ern.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0 || sales.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {

                    answer.setText("Result");


                } else {

                    double num1 = Double.parseDouble(working_capital.getText().toString());
                    double num2 = Double.parseDouble(total_assets.getText().toString());
                    double num3 = Double.parseDouble(ebit.getText().toString());
                    double num4 = Double.parseDouble(market_val_eq.getText().toString());
                    double num5 = Double.parseDouble(book_val_lib.getText().toString());
                    double num6 = Double.parseDouble(retained_ern.getText().toString());
                    double num7 = Double.parseDouble(sales.getText().toString());


                    double sum = 1.2 * (num1 / num2) + 1.4 * (num6 / num2) + 3.3 * (num3 / num2) + 0.6 * (num4 / num5) + (num7 / num2);

                    answer.setText(String.format("%.2f", sum));

                    if (sum >= 2.99) {

                        comment.setText("Successful");

                    } else if (sum <= 1.81) {

                        comment.setText("Unsuccessful");

                    } else {
                        comment.setText("Grey zone");
                    }


                }


                break;
            case R.id.button2:
                break;

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: post your stack trace

Comment: Please post your logcat error trace and xml used in this activity.

Comment: Post the logcat, b/w where are you setting onClickListener event to set to the object you want to listen to?

Comment: Thanks so much for the comments, really appreciate. The code for the button works in a new blank app. However the same code fails when placed into my trading technicals app

Answer (score 0):

Either one of the views from findViewById is returning null so NullReferenceException is thrown or one of Double.parseDouble() is receiving an empty string which will cause NumberFormatException.

So you have to check if your views are not null and before parsing check if the views contain valid text that can be parsed.

Comment: Thanks so much for your input, the code works however if i do the same thing in a blank activty

Comment: in an new app, so there must be something (probs the navigation drawer code) thats causing the crash